# jQuery UI: dynamically adding multiple selectables to an ASP.NET Razor view

Tags: css, jquery-ui, razor, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying to dynamically add more than one jQuery selectable to a razor view:

So I cannot use :

```
  $("#selectable").selectable();
```

as the id for each  element to be made selectable will be something like selectable_x where x is an integer.  The script to create the selectables goes like this:

```
function getAccordianElement(selectableId, startIdx, endIdx, routes, makeSelectable) {   


        var selectableDiv = $('<div></div>');
        var selectable = $('<ol id=' + selectableId  + '></ol>');
        selectable.addClass("selectable-container");
        selectableDiv.append(selectable);

        for (var i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++) {
            selectable.append($('<li/>', { "class": "ui-state-default", text: routes[i].Name }));
        };

        if (makeSelectable) {
           selectable.selectable();
        }


        return selectableDiv;
    }
```

and the CSS styling I am trying to use goes like so:

```
   .selectable-container.ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    .selectable-container.ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
 /* ol[id^="selectable_"] .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; } */
    .selectable-container { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    .selectable-container li { margin:1px ; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 27px; height: 25px; font-size: 1em; text-align: center; }
```

Elements are being created but the CSS styles for ui-selecting and ui-selected classes are not being applied.

Ideas greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: What do you mean by *So I cannot use $("#selectable").selectable();* ? You don't want to use that or you cannot use that ?

Comment: I need to make more than one element selectable.  $("#selectable") looks for a single element with id "selectable".  But the elemenets I want to make selectable have ids "selectable_0", "selectable_1"....

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an id (e.g. `$("#selectable")`) can you use a class instead (e.g. `$(".selectable")`)

Comment: I am applying a class .selectable-container to the selectable items which I am programmatically creating.  Hence the line  if (makeSelectable) { 
           selectable.selectable(); 
        } .  Also, the elements are being converted to selectables but my styling is not being applied.

Comment: Just found out the answer to my problem.  Selectables are being created but styling could not be applied so I changed the broken CSS rules to ol[id^="selectable_"] .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
ol[id^="selectable_"] .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; } and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works in dynamically creating multiple jQuery selectables on a single page.  Problem with the above code is the CSS rule used to find these selectables and apply the appropriate selecting and selected styles.  The broken rules are:

```
 .selectable-container.ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; } 
    .selectable-container.ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

When I changed these rules to:

```
ol[id^="selectable_"] .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
ol[id^="selectable_"] .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

as each selectable is given an id of "selectable_x" where x is an integer, the styling was successfully applied.